# How transpose a table using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose

I have a table like this:

| id | P | C | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 3 | a1 | b1 |
| 2 | 101 | 3 | a2 | b2 |
| 3 | 102 | 3 | a3 | b3 |
| 4 | 103 | 3 | a4 | b4 |
| 5 | 100 | 4 | a5 | b5 |
| 6 | 101 | 4 | a6 | b6 |
| 7 | 102 | 4 | a7 | b7 |
| 8 | 103 | 4 | a8 | b8 |

I want to get a new transposed structure like this:

| P | _3A | _3B | _4A | _4B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | a1 | b1 | a5 | b5 |
| 101 | a2 | b2 | a6 | b6 |
| 102 | a3 | b3 | a7 | b7 |
| 103 | a4 | b4 | a8 | b8 |

As you can see ,new field names have been extracted from C field in the original table.
Is there any way to do this using SQL?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: My database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Search for sql pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has some advanced functionality in terms of arrays and `crosstab`.  However, a database independent way of doing this is by using aggregation:

```
select t.p,
       max(case when c = 3 then a end) as a3,
       max(case when c = 3 then b end) as b3,
       max(case when c = 4 then a end) as a4,
       max(case when c = 4 then b end) as b4
from atable t
group by t.p;
```

This will work in both SQLite and Postgres (and just about any other database).

Comment: Thank you Gordon. It Works.

Answer (score 2):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (id INT, P INT, C INT, A VARCHAR(2), B VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1  ,100 ,3  ,'a1','b1'),
(2  ,101 ,3  ,'a2','b2'),
(3  ,102 ,3  ,'a3','b3'),
(4  ,103 ,3  ,'a4','b4'),
(5  ,100 ,4  ,'a5','b5'),
(6  ,101 ,4  ,'a6','b6'),
(7  ,102 ,4  ,'a7','b7'),
(8  ,103 ,4  ,'a8','b8')
```

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (
    SELECT P , Vals , '_' + CAST(C AS VARCHAR(10)) + N  AS Cols
    FROM @TABLE 
        UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN (A, B))up
 )A
 PIVOT (MAX(Vals)
        FOR Cols 
        IN ([_3A],[_3B],[_4A],[_4B])
        )p
```

### Result

```
╔═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╗
║  P  ║ _3A ║ _3B ║ _4A ║ _4B ║
╠═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║ 100 ║ a1  ║ b1  ║ a5  ║ b5  ║
║ 101 ║ a2  ║ b2  ║ a6  ║ b6  ║
║ 102 ║ a3  ║ b3  ║ a7  ║ b7  ║
║ 103 ║ a4  ║ b4  ║ a8  ║ b8  ║
╚═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you M.Ali. And does it work with sqlite also? Because I use SQLite in development environment. But my final dbms will be PostgreSQL.

Comment: First when you put up your question you didnt mention what RDBMS you were using, I assumed it was SQL Server and to know knowledge this should work 100% with SQL Server not to sure about other RDBMS.