# Usage of .annotate() in Django queryset with .extra() expression

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-queryset

Using this model:

```
class Mytable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    avg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    var = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I run successfully following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT id, name, 
    max(CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN avg END) as avg1, 
    max(CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN var END) as var1, 
    max(CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN avg END) as avg2, 
    max(CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN var END) as var2 
    FROM app_mytable GROUP BY name
```

My question is how can I do this query in Django? I wrote a queryset but I dont now where I have to
write "group by" expression.Or in other hand what is usage of annotate in this case?

```
q = Mytable.objects.extra(select=
    {"avg1":"max(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN avg END)",
     "var1":"max(CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN var END)",
     "avg2":"max(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN avg END)",
     "var2":"max(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN var END)"
    }).annotate(?)
```

Comment: Your SQL is rather opaque.  Can you describe in human language what your intended effect is?

Comment: See this tread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827699/how-transpose-a-table-using-sql

Comment: What rule governs which column should be ordered by?

Comment: As you can see in original SQL, there is no requirement that "order by"  be used .

Comment: You are asking about annotate and group_by.  When you call your queryset and append .values(), are you getting the data you need?  If not, what is missing?

Comment: when I use [.annotate(wl=Count('name')).values("id","name")] output only has two fields. and using [values("id","name","avg1",...)] raise this exception: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Your SELECT hardcodes 2 lines returned, of course the output has only 2 fields.

Comment: I have a feeling you are not designing your models to fit the task.  Can you change the model around?  What is the use case you are trying to solve?